# How Can I get Id value from the incoming url?

Tags: php, mysql

When users comming this link `www.sitename.com/index.php?userid=1`

But user dont need to login.

I want to do change some value for the ID =1 user at the database. How can I change value. When the user just come this url address ?

This is my index.php code: (that include some other codes about qr code)

```
<?php
  require "header.php";
  require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
  $path='img/';
  $file = $path.uniqid().".png";
?>
<?php
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
?>


    <main>
      <div class="wrapper-main">
        <section class="section-default">

          <?php

          if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
            echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
          }
          else if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
              $text="http://sitename.com/project/userid{$_SESSION["userID"]}";
            echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
               QRcode::png($text,$file,'L',10,2);
            echo "<center><img src='".$file."'></center> " ; 


}
          ?>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>

<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

**EDIT 1**

When I try this I failed where is my fault ?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['user_idx'])){
   $user_idx=$_GET['user_idx'];
   require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET balance=balance-5 WHERE user_idx='$user_idx';";
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

In the `dbh.inc.php`

```
$servername ="127.0.0.1";
$dBUsername="xx";
$dBPassword="xx";
$dBName="xx";


$conn= mysqli_connect($servername,$dBUsername,$dBPassword,$dBName);

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data being fetched from the URL directly may be accessed or retrieved via the `GET` method

For your URL `www.sitename.com/index.php?userid=1`, you may access the `userid=1` part by using the code `$_GET['userid'] // which will result into "1"`

Now, if you want to change it, you may create a link then pass a variable or new value to it:

In your case:

```
$text="http://sitename.com/project?userid{$_SESSION["userID"]}";
//we will treat the "userid" as a variable now
//so for you to fetch it, use:
//$_GET['userid']
```

Comment: dont forget to include the `?` (question mark symbol) because it for URLs, the `?` signifies that strings / letters / characters after it are variables

Comment: Thank you. So, I get the ID no with $_GET['userid'], and than in the index.php how can I change the MYSQL value for the ID 1 user. When I try to connect database and change value. I failed because index.php page is broken.

Comment: For example, ID 1 user has a balance value how can I change every time user comming this url ?

Comment: I try like this but I failed <?php
if(!empty($_GET['user_idx'])){
   $user_idx=$_GET['user_idx'];
   require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET balance=balance-5 WHERE user_idx='$user_idx';";
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

Comment: if you're calling variables inside a string, dont use the single quotation mark ` ' ' ` because it will read everything inside of it literal or as is, try using ` " " `, for example in your last comment, you said `WHERE user_idx='$user_idx' ; `, change it into `WHERE user_idx="$user_idx" ; " ; `